# Javascript Toggle Translations of Title onClick

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, translate

I have a title within a div tag. 
I need to translate the title whenever a translate button is clicked.
I have so far gotten to the point where i find the title div and want to change the contents of it by using a `languageMap`. But its not functioning! Any ideas?

```
var languageMap = {
    'English1': 'French1',
    'English2': 'French2'
}

  function translateTitle() {
    var qmTitle = document.getElementById('toolTitle')
    var qmTitleText = qmTitle.innerHTML    
    var translatedTitle = languageMap[qmTitleText]
    qmTitle.innerHTML = translatedTitle

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok If you click the title it will change according to your map

What you needed to do is add an event listener for the click event 
This sample shows you how to do that

I also exended your map so it translates backwards as well ..

```js
var languageMap = {
    'English1': 'French1',
    'English2': 'French2',
    'French1': 'English1',
    'French2': 'English2'
}
  var qmTitle = document.getElementById('toolTitle')
  function translateTitle() {
   // var qmTitle = document.getElementById('toolTitle')
    var qmTitleText = qmTitle.innerHTML    
    var translatedTitle = languageMap[qmTitleText]


    qmTitle.innerHTML = translatedTitle

  }

qmTitle.addEventListener("click", translateTitle);
```

```html
<h2 id="toolTitle">English1</h2>
```